# Do I need declare that I don't want to cache it using 'OutputCacheLocation.None'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I've often seen the 'OutputCacheLocation.None' on the web like the following site.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

And I'm wondering if I should declare it, even if I did not explicitly indicates to make it to be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need. I do at least not use it.

I'm always writing:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration=0)]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
}
```

However, I've never tried to exclude one of those properties. `NoStore` might be enough.

Comment: Just in case, you write OutputCache?

Comment: Only when I do not want to cache items or customize the cache (for instance create one cached item per language)

Answer (score 1):

Well the OutputCacheLocation is set by default to Any:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I see that the default value of the attribute 'location' is 'Any'. But what about OutputCache itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only way to set the cache policy for MVC3.

You can also apply it on the action level. Or, directly write to the response:

```
response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
```

Check out more here:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18745/ASPNET-MVC3-Caching.htm